# How to make an innerframe in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to make a frame which will be inside the main frame in tkinter. So there will be a main frame in the window, then a frame inside the main frame which will be placed but on the left side where all the data can be presented.
Please guide me on how to do this.
This is what I have tried:-

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

frame1 = ttk.Frame(root)

innerframe = tk.Frame(frame1)
innerframe.pack(side="left")

label = ttk.Label(innerframe,text="this is the left side")
label.pack(side="left")

frame1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try to play around the different options of [`Pack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#packer-options) manager.

Comment: I tried to do it, but it is still not working.

Comment: You need to make `frame1` to fill the window by adding `fill='both'` and `expand=1`.  Also to make `innerframe` to fill vertically by adding `fill='y'`. It is more easily to see the effect by setting the initial size of the root window using `geometry(...)`.

Comment: Your code is putting a frame inside another frame. Why do you think it's not?